# Jquery DataTable with server side using asmx

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, datatables

I am using Jquery Datatable 1.10.12 using server side with processing option . I tried the code from their website [JQuery Data table server side](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) but without luck . Iam doing something wrong which page is not showing records and gives error 500  Any help would be great.

My code:

.aspxpage

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#example').DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: 'EmployeeService.asmx/GetPersons'
        });
        });    
      </script>
    <body>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>BusinessEntityID</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>MiddleName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>PersonType</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>       
    </table>    
    </body>

  asmx:
    [WebMethod]
    public void GetPersons(int iDisplayLength, int iDisplayStart, int   iSortCol_0, string sSortDir_0, string sSearch )

    {
        int displayLength = iDisplayLength;
        int displayStart = iDisplayStart;
        int sortCol = iSortCol_0;
        string  sortDir = sSortDir_0;
        string search = sSearch;
        List<Person> pdetails = new List<Person>();
        int filteredcount = 0;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(("spGetPersons"), con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter pDisplayLength = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@DisplayLength",
                Value = displayLength
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pDisplayLength);
            SqlParameter pDisplayStart = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@DisplayStart",
                Value = displayStart
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pDisplayStart);
            SqlParameter pSortCol = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@SortCol",
                Value = sortCol
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pSortCol);
            SqlParameter pSortDir = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@SortDir",
                Value = sortDir
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pSortDir);
            SqlParameter pSearchString = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@Search",
                Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(search)?null:search
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pSearchString);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Person per = new Person();
                per.BusinessEntityID = rdr["BusinessEntityID"].ToString();
                filteredcount = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["TotalCount"].ToString());
                per.FirstName = rdr["FirstName"].ToString();
                per.MiddleName = rdr["MiddleName"].ToString();
                per.LastName = rdr["LastName"].ToString();
                per.PersonType = rdr["PersonType"].ToString();
                pdetails.Add(per);
            }
        }

        var result = new
        {

            draw = 1, 
            recordsTotal = GetPersonsTotalCount(),
            recordsFiltered = filteredcount,
            data = pdetails
        };

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        js.MaxJsonLength = 2147483644;
       Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(result));
    }

    private int GetPersonsTotalCount()
    {
        int totalPersonCount = 0;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(("select count(*) from Person.Person"), con);
            con.Open();
            totalPersonCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        return totalPersonCount;
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string BusinessEntityID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string PersonType { get; set; }

    }

   JSON :

  {"draw":1,"recordsTotal":19972,"recordsFiltered":19972,"data":[{"BusinessEntityID":"1","FirstName":"Ken","MiddleName":"J","LastName":"Sánchez","PersonType":"EM"},{"BusinessEntityID":"2","FirstName":"Terri","MiddleName":"Lee","LastName":"Duffy","PersonType":"EM"},{"BusinessEntityID":"3","FirstName":"Roberto","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Tamburello","PersonType":"EM"},{"BusinessEntityID":"4","FirstName":"Rob","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Walters","PersonType":"EM"},{"BusinessEntityID":"5","FirstName":"Gail","MiddleName":"A","LastName":"Erickson","PersonType":"EM"},{"BusinessEntityID":"6","FirstName":"Jossef","MiddleName":"H","LastName":"Goldberg","PersonType":"EM"},{"BusinessEntityID":"7","FirstName":"Dylan","MiddleName":"A","LastName":"Miller","PersonType":"EM"},{"BusinessEntityID":"8","FirstName":"Diane","MiddleName":"L","LastName":"Margheim","PersonType":"EM"},{"BusinessEntityID":"9","FirstName":"Gigi","MiddleName":"N","LastName":"Matthew","PersonType":"EM"},{"BusinessEntityID":"10","FirstName":"Michael","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Raheem","PersonType":"EM"}]}
```

ERROR :

> http://localhost:64400/EmployeeService.asmx/GetPersons?draw=1&columns%5B0%5…art=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1478471333896
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error) Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in
>   '/GetPersons'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is
>   unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetPersons'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL
>   unexpectedly ending in '/GetPersons'.]
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type
>   type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
>   +169669    System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext
>   context, String verb, String url, String filePath) +209
>   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext
>   context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +120
>   System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +339    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Answer (score 0):

Please Modify your Asmx FIle like

```
 [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
    public void GetPersons(int iDisplayLength, int iDisplayStart, int   iSortCol_0, string sSortDir_0, string sSearch )

{
}
```

Modifi web config add protocols inside webServices

```
<system.web>
<webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
```

Comment: Hi Rajshee . Thanks for the help & code. I have [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]  in my xxx. asmx.cs file .  [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class ABCDetailService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {   [WebMethod]
         [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
         public void GetPersons(int iDisplayLength, int iDisplayStart, int iSortCol_0, string sSortDir_0, string sSearch)
         {            }

Comment: ERROR: System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: iDisplayLength.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

Comment: please pass all parameter value in ajax call

Comment: Personally, I have had much more success with my web methods using a post instead of a get.